# Ubuntu in my MacBook Pro

Tags: macos, ubuntu

I was trying to dual boot linux with mac os x. Everything was fine, until i tried to switch from ubuntu back to os x. After typing my password, this happened. (I couldn't submit the image, but it is a blackscreen with a white logo indicating that it is prohibited. Imagine the "no parking allowed" sign without the letter E)

I was thinking of overwriting ubuntu and make linux my only os, and then try to reinstall os x. Any tips or can someone help me solve this? Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

1. Attempt to reset the NVRAM to see if it helps out finding the startup volume

NVRAM 
https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204063

2. Boot to the recovery partition by holding down the CMD+R keys on startup and use the startup manager to select your boot volume.

Hope this helps